# Multiple form dynamic field javascript validation

Tags: javascript, php, html

**I have multiple form like this:**

```
<?php for ($i = 0; $i > $n; $i++) { ?> // n is no. of value (no limit)
    <form>
        <input name="<?php echo $i; ?>venue" type="text">
        <input name="roster" type="text">
        <input type="submit" name="btn_venue">

    </form>
<?php } ?>
    <form>
        <input name="hospitality" type="text">
        <input name="template" type="text">
        <input type="submit" name="btn_hospitality">
    </form>
    ...
    ...
    <form>
        <input name="element" type="text">
        <input name="alignment" type="text">
        <input type="submit" name="btn_xyz">
    </form>
```

I want validate(field should not be blank) in all form so, how can I use validation ?

I tried jQuery validation:

```
<script>
    $('document').ready(function () {
        $('form').each(function (key, form) {
            $(form).validate({
                rules: {
                    hospitality: {
                        required: true
                    },
                    //...
                    //...
                    alignment: {
                        required: true
                    }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

I have manage static name field validation but I don't idea about dynamic `venue` name validation.Can anyone help me ?

if only one form the easily maintain but dynamically multiple form submit validate how to validate.

at a time only one form submit but particular form field validate how it is possible?

Comment: How you are submitting form? You don't have submit buttons..?

Comment: @StefanMichelangeloMihajlovic updated Code please check it.

Comment: Add "required" attribute in the inputs that is required, browsers with HTML5 support will automactilly validate it. If you wanna custom error message you can use Parsley.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this. It goes through each form and for each of them through each input (of type text) and builds a required rule for each of them. Then feeds the dynamically built rules to the validate function.

```
$('document').ready(function () {
    $('form').each(function (key, form) {
        // build the rules object dynamically
        var rules = {};
        // loop through each input in the form
        $(form).find('input[type="text"]').each(function(idx, obj) {
            // make a rule for this input
            rules[obj.name] = {"required": true};
        });
        $(form).validate({
            "rules": rules
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Okey this is not for sure the cleanest way to do this but its the first that cross my mind.
First, edit your html, so form has `id="form$i",` input has `id="input$i",` and submit has `id="$i"`. Also add class to submit `class="validate"`

```
<?php for ($i = 0; $i > $n; $i++) { ?> // n is no. of value (no limit)
    <form id="form<?php echo $i; ?>">//so id="form2" for example
        <input id="input<?php echo $i; ?>" name="<?php echo i; ?>venue" type="text">// id="input2"
        <input name="roster" type="text">
        <input id="<?php echo $i; ?>" class="validate" type="submit" name="btn_venue">//id="2"
    </form>
<?php } ?>
```

JQuery which should work, I'll explain each line in code

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        $(".validate").click(function () { //this is call for each click button with class validate
            var id = $(this).attr('id');//getting id of the clicked element which is $i
            var formid = 'form' + id;//creating new var formid which will target formid (for example: in first loop $i=1, so id=1, and formid=form1)
            var input = 'input' + id;//creating input which value will be input$i
            $('#' + formid).on('submit', function (e) {//on form submit validate function
                if ($(#input).value == '') {
                    return false;
                } else {
                    return true;
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

hope you understand logic, it might be I made mistake somewhere so take a close look..